# Making 5 balls using turtle graphics and having them interact with the edge of the screen

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am relatively new to programming and I am trying to figure out how to make this work. I have most of it done (i think). I just have no idea how to make the two functions interact with each other. Please nothing too complex I am still learning and would like to work within the boundaries of my own type of coding.

Here is my code

```
import turtle
import random

win = turtle.Screen()
win.setup(width=500, height=500, startx=80, starty=80)
win.title("Balls Bounce")
win.bgcolor("white")


def ball():
    x = turtle.Turtle(shape="circle")
    x.penup()
    x.showturtle()
    x.setheading(random.randrange(360))
    x.forward(5)


def falling():
    x = turtle.position()[0]
    y = turtle.position()[1]
    if x < -250 or x > 250 or y < -250 or y > 250:
        turtle.forward(-5)
        turtle.setheading(random.randrange(360))
        turtle.forward(5)


for i in range(5):
    ball()


while True:
    falling()
```

Comment: first you should keep balls on list. Later you can use balls from list to move them.

Answer (score 0):

First you should return ball created in `ball()` and add to list

And later use this list in `falling()` to move balls.

```
import turtle
import random

# --- functions ---

def ball():
    x = turtle.Turtle(shape="circle")
    x.penup()
    x.showturtle()
    x.setheading(random.randrange(360))
    x.forward(5)
    return x  # <-- return ball

def falling():
    for b in balls:  # <-- use ball from list

        b.forward(5)

        x = b.position()[0]
        y = b.position()[1]
        if x < -250 or x > 250 or y < -250 or y > 250:
            b.forward(-5)
            b.setheading(random.randrange(360))
            b.forward(5)

# --- main ---

win = turtle.Screen()
win.setup(width=500, height=500, startx=80, starty=80)
win.title("Balls Bounce")
win.bgcolor("white")

balls = []
for i in range(5):
    b = ball()
    balls.append(b)  # <-- keep ball on list

while True:
    falling()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate your help.